# Discrete time sine wave generation near nyquist

Tags: discrete-signals, cosine

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to generate sine-waves out of a DAC near the Nyquist frequency (or determining how close I can get for reliable results). So if I want to generate a 499 Hz sine wave using a 1 kSPS DAC, I will calculate each sample:

$$y(t) = \sin(2 \pi 499 \ t) $$

Converting this to discrete time:

$$ y[k] = y\left( \tfrac{k}{1000} \right) = \sin \left(2 \pi 499 \frac{k}{1000} \right)$$

I end up with something like this:

[image]

The red line shows the 499 Hz signal, while the blue dots show the DAC sample. I get these large amplitude fluctuations. I know it's common to use a reconstruction filter to get rid of DAC images, which I always thought of as a low-pass filter from DC to Nyquist, which wouldn't really help get rid of the amplitude fluctuations...or would it?

Is there a better approach for generating sine waves? Or is there just simply a limit I cannot exceed (and what is the limit)?

Comment: so this is a *"conventional"* DAC and not an oversampled sigma-delta DAC?  if that is the case, and you **really** want to generate good sinusoids up to nearly Nyquist, you will need a helluva sharp brickwall LPF as an anti-imaging filter.

Comment: oversampling (which is one of the techniques of sigma-delta) is far cheaper than an analog brick-wall LPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong about this – it's absolutely what you should be seeing.

The sine wave is intact, if you applied a reconstruction filter – there's no amplitude fluctuation of the wave, as soon as you limit its bandwidth to the nyquist bandwidth, the analog signal "has" to follow the full sines.

Comment: well, Marcus, there **is** something wrong with this.  his anti-imaging filter isn't sharp enough, but that's a damn hard task for an analog filter.

Comment: well, you're right about the realizability of the filter, but he's not using any filter at all so far.

Comment: that's true, but his output beating like it is, is **wrong**.  but the solution is oversampling and staying the hell away from Nyquist.

Comment: The output beating is 100% right! Look at the beat frequency: exactly the 1 Hz that's left between Nyquist and his oscillation.

Comment: (that's by the way an excellent illustration of why that brickwall filter would have to be incredibly long in time domain: you need the energy of 500 adjacent samples to reconstruct the sine with a constant envelope)

Comment: I'll hence go with "the output beating is mathematically expected, but it makes this approach infeasible unless you have a magical 1/500-passband transition width analog filter"

Comment: i am starting to suspect that this is not really about a DAC.  it's more about mathematical reconstruction and the OP doesn't quite grok the reconstruction part of the sampling theorem.

Comment: Looking at that, I think you're right.

Comment: Thanks. What I was failing to see was that the low frequency beats were actually a result of the combination of the main frequency and the higher frequency image. So a LPF would remove the image and give a nice flat sinusoid train.